# Understanding UWP stack trace with .NET native toolchain

Tags: .net, uwp, stack-trace, crash-dumps, .net-native

I've published an UWP app to the store with crash analytics and I'm trying to understand how to ""decrypt"" the stacktraces, here is what I got:

```
 PagesManager!<BaseAddress>+0xcfdd01 at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x38449f at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3842cd Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x384405 at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3bd80d at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3c1f45 at
 PagesManager!<BaseAddress>+0xd18017 at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x2f87a7 at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x2f877d at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3844c7 at
 SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x3842ab
```

I've looked everywhere and tried to use windbg, and cvdump without any success, those posts are also old so I though that it should be another solution by now.

Any idea on how can I get an actual stacktrace, not that I have the pdbs files (downloaded from the dev center) and all intermediate build files.

Thanks

Comment: You can use HockeyApp to help you collect crashes which are symbolicated. HockeyApp can help collect effective crashes for both windows store app and beta distribution app.

Comment: I understand that hockey app has the pdb upload feature which allow it to "decode" the stacktrace, still isn't there anything else that I can do to fix the crashes that I have now?

Comment: Without PDBs, that's typically all you'll get